# Не записываются snmp trap в файл [ubuntu]

Tags: ubuntu, snmp

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

Установил snmpd snmptt snmp.

/etc/default/snmpd

```
# This file controls the activity of snmpd

# Don't load any MIBs by default.
# You might comment this lines once you have the MIBs downloaded.
export MIBS=

# snmpd control (yes means start daemon).
SNMPDRUN=yes

# snmpd options (use syslog, close stdin/out/err).
SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u snmp -g snmp -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -p /run/snmpd.pid'
```

/etc/snmp/snmptt.ini

```
mode =daemon
net_snmp_perl_enable = 1
log_file = /var/log/snmptt/snmptt.log
log_enable = 1
unknown_trap_log_enable = 1
unknown_trap_log_file = /var/log/snmptt/snmpttunknown.log
```

/etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf

```
authCommunity log,execute,net public
traphandle default snmptthandler
```

Трапы не записываются вообще, хотя по tcpdump они приходят.

Если запускать вручную:

```
sudo service snmpd stop
sudo snmptrapd -f -L o
```

то всё записывается.
А также в логах:

```
16:45:03 2017/04/18 SNMPTT v1.4 shutdown
16:45:03 2017/04/18 Total traps received=0,Total traps translated=0,Total traps ignored=0,Total unknown traps=0
16:45:04 2017/04/18 SNMPTT v1.4 started
16:45:04 2017/04/18 Loading /etc/snmp/snmptt.conf
16:45:04 2017/04/18 Finished loading 66 lines from /etc/snmp/snmptt.conf
16:45:04 2017/04/18 Loading
16:45:04 2017/04/18 Could not open configuration file:
16:45:04 2017/04/18 Changing to UID: snmptt (117)
```

Что я делаю не так?
Could not open configuration file: - пытался гуглить, ничего толком не нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог запуск с параметром snmptrapd -On

Answer (score 1):

*Changing to UID: snmptt* намекает, что работает оно от пользователя snmptt.
Ему conf-файл (/etc/snmp/snmptt.ini) доступен для чтения? А /var/log/snmptt/ доступен для записи?

Просто так вы пробуете от рута, у него прав больше.

Comment: Достаточно chmod сделать или назначить владельца (chown)?

Comment: смотря куда. НА ini лучше срьщв сделать (только не 666!), а на каталог с логами лучше назначить владельцем.

Comment: Не помогло. https://codeshare.io/GApbRw при запуске snmptt --debug=2

Comment: Его не устраивает 66 строка файла /etc/snmp/snmptt.conf. Покажите этот файл.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/GbebNq странно, ничего не вижу 66 строка EDESC

Comment: Помог запуск с параметром snmptrapd -On

Answer (score 0):

у вас есть - /etc/snmp/snmptt.ini.  а программа вам пишет - Loading /etc/snmp/snmptt.conf. и ничего прочитать не может - нет там snmptt.conf, вместо него snmptt.ini.
поменяйте .ini на .conf и все прочитается.